# Programmatically Re-Layout Visio Flowchart

Tags: c#, visio

I read in from an Excel file and create a Visio flowchart using this information (this is all fine). Once the diagram has been completed I can then manually edit my Flowchart.

What I want to do is after all of the shapes have been added and they are all dropped in place, I want to programmatically use the Design -> Re-Layout -> Flowchart -> RightToLeft.

I am using `Visio.VisAutoConnectDir.visAutoConnectDirLeft` when I autoconnect my shapes, but I want to Re-Layout after all of my shapes have been dropped.

I can do it fine manually, just not programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

There's a method on the Page and Selection objects, called Layout, that should do what you want:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff766448(v=office.14).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff766448%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

It should be the equivalent of clicking the re-layout button.